# Scala, Play2.0 - Expected ';' but found ')'

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

This seems to be a common theme for newbie Scala programmers like myself...

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(defaultJavaSettings:_*).settings(
    resolvers += Resolver.file("private") artifacts "C:/java/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "C:/java/repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"
    resolvers += Resolver.url("public") artifacts "https://foo.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "https://foo.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"
)
```

These two lines together produce the error:

```
[error] C:\java\play-2.0-beta\base\project\Build.scala:16: ')' expected but '.' found.
[error]         resolvers += Resolver.url("webster") artifacts "https://dev.blackrock.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "https://dev.blackrock.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"
[error]                              ^
[error] C:\java\play-2.0-beta\base\project\Build.scala:17: ';' expected but ')' found.
[error]     )
[error]     ^
[error] two errors found
```

If I remove one line, it works, doesn't matter which one.  Changing the order of the lines makes no difference.

Can anyone steer me right?

Comment: aren't those resolvers arguments to the settings function? (disclaimer: no play knowledge)

Comment: That's the hint I needed.  I put the resolvers in separate chained settings calls and that fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `results += ....` is a parameter. What you wrote is, essentially, this:

```
val main = PlayProject(...).settings(a b)
```

What you should have written is this:

```
val main = PlayProject(...).settings(a, b) // put in a comma!
```

Though you could also have written this:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(defaultJavaSettings:_*).settings(
  resolvers ++= Seq(
    Resolver.file("private") artifacts "C:/java/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "C:/java/repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml",
    Resolver.url("public") artifacts "https://foo.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "https://foo.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"
  )
)
```

Comment: This was a long time ago, and I haven't tried it, but it makes sense and is the top voted answer, so I'm giving Daniel the credit...

Answer (score 1):

Chaining two calls to settings fixed the problem.

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(defaultJavaSettings:_*).settings(
    resolvers += Resolver.file("private") artifacts "C:/java/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "C:/java/repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"
).settings(
    resolvers += Resolver.url("public") artifacts "https://foo.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "https://foo.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to skip lines between resolvers.

Comment: You mean adding an extra newline somehow makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You simply missed comma between first and second resolvers

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(defaultJavaSettings:_*).settings(
      resolvers += Resolver.file("private") artifacts "C:/java/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "C:/java/repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"
    , resolvers += Resolver.url("public") artifacts "https://foo.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" ivys "https://foo.com/ivy-repository/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"
)
```

Comment: This is from a long time ago, but I tried that after the answer from Daniel, and it still didn't work.